# Projecting texture without adding border to it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem when using the projector with an image as a texture. How to set wrap mode neither to repeat nor to clamp texture?
I want to get this:

[image]

and not this:

[image]
(Images are from [this](http://talarian.blogspot.co.at/p/unity-tutorial.html) tutorial)

I run into few solutions to this problem and all of them use Advanced Texture Type which is not available in newer versions of the Unity.
*"...What you'll want to do in that case is go to your texture, change the type from Texture to **Advanced**..."*

Is there any replacement for that problem?

**EDIT:**

As @Gunnar B mentioned, I haven't realized that in the tutorial 1px border is used, so selecting Advanced is not a solution to the problem.

So my question is how to get projection as seen in the first image without adding the border?

Comment: Well, at least up to 2017.3.1 advanced is still there. Border mipmaps (which is what should be checked according to the tutorial) should be there anyways. Please add a picture from you texture (in the inspector). Also, another point in the tutorial is that you should leave a 1 pixel border on your image to prevent something like you get.

Comment: Ohh I understood that wrong, I thought when Advanced has selected it results in the upper image. Haven't seen that with a 1px border. There is Advanced in my inspector with mentioned checkbox but I think that it is not a problem if I have to add the border.
Is it possible to somehow do it without 1px border?

Comment: No, it is impossible without adding a 1px border. The rending code needs to know what color to draw when outside the image boundary size. It can't magically guess.